# ORACLE SQL: How to link 2 tables that do not have common unid

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am very new to ORACLE SQL and I have a question about linking 2 tables that don't have a common unid. I have 2 tables:  job and sea.  the job table is linked with the sea table through a connection with a lotno ref job unid.  I would like to get the container type and qty of containers for the entire lot.

Here is some sample data.

Table JOB:

```
| unid  | lotno      | shipno      | etd    | eta    |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| 10001 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00801 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10002 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00816 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10003 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00818 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10004 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00820 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10005 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00823 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10006 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00843 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10007 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00844 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10008 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00847 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10009 | SHSEM01198 | SHASEH00851 | 13-May | 11-Jun |
| 10010 |            | SHSEM01198  | 13-May | 11-Jun |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Table SEA

```
| job_unid | containerno | conttype |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| 10010    | TSLU55820   | 40HC     |
| 10010    | CAIU69851   | 40HC     |
| 10010    | TKLU56578   | 40HC     |
| 10010    | MASC5008    | 20ST     |
| 10010    | DESU5587    | 20ST     |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Desired Result

```
| lotno          | shipno      | etd    | eta    | Conttype1 | Conttype1_qty | Conttype2 | Conttype2_Qty | Conttype3 | Conttype3_Qty |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00801 | 13-May | 11-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00816 | 13-May | 12-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00818 | 13-May | 13-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00820 | 13-May | 14-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00823 | 13-May | 15-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00843 | 13-May | 16-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00844 | 13-May | 17-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00847 | 13-May | 18-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
| SHSEM01198     | SHASEH00851 | 13-May | 19-Jun | 40HC      | 3             | 20ST      | 2             |           |               |
+----------------+-------------+--------+--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
```

The lotno also has a shpno and unid which is the link to the sea table.

Really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on this!

Comment: From your sample data, what are examples of `the job table is linked with the sea table through a connection with a lotno ref job unid` and `The lotno also has a shpno and unid which is the link to the sea table.`

Comment: `The lotno also has a shpno and unid which is the link to the sea table` -- How? I don't see it. Also, where does `Conttype1_qty` come from?

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick responses:
So each job will have a lotno to link the jobs together (example: SHSEM01198  ) , but also that same lotno is also a shipno and has a unid (10010).  The SEA table is connected to the job table based on that unid (10010).

The container type is a aggregate total of that unid (10010) conttype and qty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think is the task:

1. You are looking for job records with a lotno.
2. Each of these job records has another job record attatched whose shipno matches its lotno.
3. Now you want to count sea records per job_unid and conttype and join this result to the jobs.
4. However, you don't want a list of all job-sea combinations, but a list of jobs only, each job with up to three sea content types.

In order to achieve the latter, you must number your aggregated sea rows.

```
with s as
(
  select
    job_unid,
    conttype,
    count(*) as qty,
    row_number() over (partition by job_unid order by conttype) as rn
  from sea
  group by job_unid, conttype
)
select
  j1.lotno, j1.shipno, j1.etd, j1.eta,
  s1.conttype as conttype1, s1.qty as conttype1_qty,
  s2.conttype as conttype2, s2.qty as conttype2_qty,
  s3.conttype as conttype3, s3.qty as conttype3_qty
from job j1
join job j2 on j2.shipno = j1.lotno
left join s s1 on s1.job_unid = j2.unid and s1.rn = 1
left join s s2 on s2.job_unid = j2.unid and s2.rn = 2
left join s s3 on s3.job_unid = j2.unid and s3.rn = 3
order by j1.lotno, j1.shipno;
```